# Load image elements via AJAX in a preferred sequence

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery

hi
i am loading images on my web site after page load with jquery, i use $(document).ready to load images after page load now i want to specify order so i can load images of my slide show in a manner and have my slide show hidden, after slide show picture load show it.

this is an html part of my code:

```
 <a class="videoThumb imageLightbox" href="images/slider/pic-usa-11-large.jpg">

                    <img src="/images/blank.gif" class="delayLoad" onmouseover="this.src = './images/slider/pic-usa-11.jpg'"   width=" 215px" height="160px"/>
                  </a>
```

and i load images after document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Load images once the page has loaded
    jQuery("img.delayLoad").each(function() {

        // Create a new span element which we will wrap around our image
        // Using a span because if the image was inside an <a> tag then online inline elements should be used
        var delaySpan =  document.createElement("span");

        with (jQuery(this)) {
            // Handle images that are hidden, otherwise display mode for the span should be block (inline doesn't work properly)
            if (css('display') == 'none') {
                var _display = 'none' } else {
                var _display = 'block' }

            // Copy the style from the image into a new object (this means you don't need to worry about styling this span within your CSS)
            var cssObj = {
                'height' : css('height'),
                'width' : css('width'),
                'margin-top' : css('margin-top'),
                'margin-right' : css('margin-right'),
                'margin-bottom' : css('margin-bottom'),
                'margin-left' : css('margin-left'),
                'background-image' : css('background-image'),
                'background-color' : css('background-color'),
                'background-repeat' : css('background-repeat'),
                // Hack for now, becuase IE doesn't seem to read the background-position property correctly
                'background-position' : '50% 50%',
                'display' : _display
            }
        }

        // Apply our style properties to our span    
        jQuery(delaySpan).css(cssObj);

        // Wrap the image in the span
        jQuery(this).wrap(delaySpan)

        // Hide the image (leaving just the span visible
        .hide()

        // Simulate the mouse over the image, whcih will cause it to switch the img src
        .mouseover()

        // Remove the mouseover attribute (since we don't want to update the img src every time the user does a mouseover
        .removeAttr("onmouseover")

        // Simulate the mouse moving out of the image (To reset the image to its normal state)
        .mouseout()

        // Once the image is loaded, perform a function
        .load(function () {
            // Fade the image in
            // Remove the span by unwrapping the image
            jQuery(this).fadeIn().unwrap();
        });
    });    

});
```

(i used this document: http://www.purplepixelmedia.co.uk/Ourblog/tabid/78/articleType/ArticleView/articleId/80/Using-jQuery-to-loading-images-after-the-page-is-ready.aspx )

now i want to control images load and hide the box before all images are loaded and show the box after page load

how do i can do such task?

thanks

Comment: Can we have the detail of your code? It will help us to give you a more accurate answer.

Comment: Well, what framework are you using on the server side and how are you retrieving the images? Can we see photos? It might make the best sense to sort them on the server side and return one huge list, rather then make a crazy amount of AJAX calls for each one, because then you might have to use synchronous AJAX to retrieve them, which is kind of against the point of AJAX to begin with. But I can't really tell you anything without code.

Comment: @julkiewicz  hi dear friend you are right but with no real solution i should accept it? or wait to get a better answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [jQuery Message Queueing](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-message-queuing/docs/files/jquery-ba-jqmq-js.html) plugin lets you perform serial AJAX requests. This may be what you're looking for.